# Relative Growth Rate Question: A bacteria culture initially contains 100 cells and grows at a rate proportional to its size.

Tags: calculus

A bacteria culture initially contains 100 cells and grows at a rate proportional to its size. After an hour the population has increased to 420.

(a) Find an expression for the number of bacteria after t hours.

$y(t)=y(0)e^{kt}=100e^{kt}$

$y(0)=100$

$y(1)=420$

$y(1)=\frac{100e^{k(1)}}{100}=\frac{420}{100}$

$\ln\ e^{k\cdot1}=\ln\ 4.2$

$k=ln\ 4.2$

Thus, $y(t)=100e^{(\ln\ 4.2)\cdot t}$

(b) Find the rate of growth after 3 hours

I am having a hard time understanding how to utilize the formula given:

The instructions are the following:

> What is the significance of the proportionality constant K? In the
>   context of population growth, where P(t) is the size of a population
>   at time $t$, we write
>
> $\frac{dP}{dt}= kP$
>
> or
>
> $\frac{1}{p}\ \frac{dP}{dt} = k$

I don't understand how to utilize this information. To be quite honest, I'm not sure what the fraction $\frac{dP}{dt}$ really means. Can someone explain at my level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dP}{dt}$ is the “instantaneous” rate of change of the population. Formally, it’s the derivative of the population size function with respect to time. So, the equation $\frac{dP}{dt}=kP$ just says that the growth rate at any instant is proportional to the population at that time, which you already knew.

Now that you’ve computed $k$, you just plug it into the growth rate formula above, setting $P$ to the population size at $3$ hours, i.e., $\frac{dP}{dt}(3 hrs) = kP(3 hrs) = \ln 4.2 \cdot 100e^{3 \ln{4.2}} = {4.2}^3\cdot100\cdot\ln{4.2}$.

Comment: Let me start by saying thank you for your help. Nonetheless, k = the relative growth rate. I calculated it in the initial question. However, the question is asking for the rate of growth after three hours, not the number of bacteria after 3 hours. Any ideas? The student manual explains it this way: $\frac{dP}{dt}$=kP $\rightarrow$ $P'(3)=k\cdot P(3)$=$(\ln4.2)(100(4.2)^3)$ [from part a] $\approx10632$ bacteria \ h. I don't understand where the e went?

Comment: To answer your second question, $e^{b\ln a}=a^b$. For your first, I’ve added to my answer.